Execute Winget install command in msi installer made by WIX 4.0.5
I have powershell script which I would like to run with help of WIX Custom Action. Inside this script I have winget install command which I would like to use in order to install dotnet runtime.
Custom action in WIX:
    <CustomAction Id="RunDotNetInstallerTest" 
                  Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" 
                  ExeCommand="powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command &quot; &amp; { .\Scripts\dotnet-runtime-installer.ps1 } *> 'C:\install-log.txt'&quot;" 
                  Execute="deferred"
                  Return="check"
                  Impersonate="no" />
...
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="RunDotNetInstallerTest" Before="InstallFinalize" />
        </InstallExecuteSequence>

PowerShell script:
# Check if winget is available
if ((Get-Command "winget" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "winget is not installed. Please install winget and try again."
    exit
}

# Install a package using winget
try {
    winget install --id=Microsoft.DotNet.DesktopRuntime.6 --accept-package-agreements --accept-source-agreements -e
    Write-Host "Desktop runtime installed successfully."
} catch {
    Write-Host "Failed to install Desktop runtime."
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}

This custom action runs script well during installation. But when it comes to check is winget command present ((Get-Command "winget" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) this check returns true, which means it cannot find winget command.
If I run this script manually (admin rights or current user) from cmd  or powershell it works well and installs runtime, but when it comes to WIX installer it cannot find winget command.

It looks like inside scripts you might need to specify full path to Winget. You can read more on it here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-intune/app-installation-with-powershell-and-winget/m-p/4002646

Thank you for your help.
I found the solution but forgot to write it down.
Main issue that when you're running wix msi it is runs with administrator privileges. In this case, my administrator does not have winget, because it is located in my current user folder.

I found what is the issue.
The main moment we have in who is running WIX msi file.
When you're running msi from your own local user, msi ask for admin rights. As soon as you give access to it, msi continue its work in administrator area and will use data from administrator folder.
In my case, my administrator does not have winget in its folder, because it is located in my current user folder.
